# Geometric meaning of being integrally closed in some overring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

The geometric counterpart of integrally closed rings (in their fraction fields) are normal varieties, as described in [this MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1504/what-is-the-geometric-meaning-of-integral-closure).

Is their a similar notion in algebraic geometry for being integrally closed in some ring $S$, when $S$ is not necessarily the fraction field?

Comment: If $f: X\to Y$ is a dominant morphism of algebraic varieties, one can construct the normalization $Y'$ of $Y$ in $X$: this is an integral variety such that $f$ factors through $X\to Y'\to Y$, where $Y'\to Y$ is finite and anything between $X$ and $Y'$, finite over $Y'$, is necessarily equal to $Y'$.  The $X$ correspond to your $S$ and $Y$ the base ring.

Comment: I should have said that $X$ and $Y$ are integral algebraic varieties.

Comment: And do you mean rational maps or total maps?

Comment: Total (morphism).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer by cant_log with a reference. One can consider the normalization of $Y$ in $X$ if $f : X \to Y$ is a quasi-compact and quasi-separated morphism of schemes, see [Section Tag 035E](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/035E). The normalization of $Y$ in $X$ is a factorization $X \to Y' \to Y$ of $f$ such that for every affine open $V \subset Y$ the inverse image $V'$ of $V$ in $Y'$ is also affine and such that
$$
\mathcal{O}_{Y'}(V') = \{g \in \mathcal{O}_X(f^{-1}(V)) \mid g\text{ is integral over }\mathcal{O}_Y(V)\}
$$
This will at least tell you how to construct $Y'$ if $Y$ is affine and in general you just glue the affine pieces together. In particular, if $X \to Y$ is the morphism associated to a ring map $B \to A$, then $Y'$ is the spectrum of the integral closure of $B$ in $A$.

So the analogue of "$B$ being integrally closed in $A$" would be "the normalization of $Y$ in $X$ is $Y$", in other words, $Y = Y'$.